# Xpath get td of a row based on the contents of another td

Tags: html, xpath

I have a table that has 100 rows. A standard row looks like this:

```
`<tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>London</td>
    <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
</tr>`
```

The data will obviously change for each row, however I want to be able to select the link of the first row where the name of the person is John Smith.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath helped me out a great deal.

xpath=//tr[td='John Smith'][1]/td[4]/a

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath using the `following-sibling::`-axis:

```
tr/td[text()='John Smith']/following-sibling::td/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//td[contains(text(), 'John Smith')]//a
```

Get link with your corresponding syntax for

```
getAttribute('href')
```